# SQL Server: error when connecting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tcp

The application I'm using tries to connect SQL Server named instance running on a dedicated database server. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host <instance_name>, port 1433 has failed. Error: Connection refused: connect.
```

Is the firewall blocking my access or what? Should I dedicate a different port for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refused connect implies that your connection does not have permissions to connect to this instance of SQL Server.

Are you using Windows Authentication or a SQL Server Login?

For troubleshooting guidelines see: [Troubleshooting Server and Database Connection Problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156468.aspx)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Windows authentication.